# Will the netinstall (minimal) work with a USB cellular modem?

Tags: installation, usb-modem, ubuntu-minimal

Installing Ubuntu minimal is extremely easy when the system has a LAN card and connected to internet via Cable & Router...

I Recently came across a situation where I needed to install Ubuntu Minimal on a system which wash not having a LAN card and cable internet anywhere around... 
**The only access to the internet was through a USB Plug n Play Data-Card Modem.**

May anyone suggest something so that I may install Ubuntu Minimal using USB Modem as the only source of Internet, if it's possible at all?? (This relates to Ubuntu 12.04 in specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the minimal image includes only wired drivers and limited wireless (WiFi) support. What you want is not possible with the default `mini.iso`, although you can of course remaster it to include the necessary modules. Use the expert install, so you can drop to a shell (busybox) before the network detection part and load the modules, set the IP, etc.

Comment: My you please suggest the workout to this.. Generally on a full installed system, the very moment i plug the USB modem, a CDFS file system mounts for the first time from where i install a .deb package... once installed, i get an menu option under internt; to launch its GUI and to manually dial the internet.